# Implicit route model binding 401 unauthorized

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a super simple learning app. My Laravel version is `5.5.13`. A `User` can create a `Pet`. I am implicitly throwing `404` but I need to also implicitly throw `401` is this possible?

Details on setup:

`Pet` model:

```
class Pet extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'user_id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

And `User` model giving the relationship `hasMany`:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    // ... some stuff hidden for brevity

    public function pets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Pet');
    }
}
```

I used implicit route model binding to throw `404` status when the id is not found like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::get('pets', 'PetController@index');
    Route::get('pets/{pet}', 'PetController@show');
    Route::post('pets', 'PetController@store');
    Route::put('pets/{pet}', 'PetController@update');
    Route::delete('pets/{pet}', 'PetController@delete');
});
```

Notice the `{pet}` instead of `{id}`.

However I also want to throw `401` unauthorized status if the `$pet->user_id` does not equal `Auth::guard('api')->user()->id`. Is this implicitly possible?

If not possible, may you please show me how to explicitly do this in the controller? I was doing this, but I don't think it's the recommended way is it?

```
public function show(Pet $pet)
{
    if ($pet->user_id != Auth::guard('api')->user()->id) {
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Not authenticated to view this pet'], 401);
    }
    return $pet;
}
```

Comment: On a side note if you look at resource routes you do not need to define all the routes as you have done above, this can all be handled by Laravel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more Laravel centric way todo this is using [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#creating-policies).

Then for each action you want to authorize you register them inside your policy. Your `show` method would then become:

```
public function show(Pet $pet)
{
    $this->authorize('show', $pet);

    return $pet;
}
```

So your steps would be:

- Create a new Policy for Pets
- Add the actions you want to authorize
- Register the policy in the `AuthServiceProvider`
- Use the `authorize`
  call inside your Controller action

Comment: It is working awesomely sir! It even throws a `403` which is better then what I wanted, I thought to throw `401` thank you!!